# JBoss AS 7.0.2 - no print services found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

My problem is that the following piece of code does not find any printers when run inside JBoss AS 7 (doesn't matter if its within an EJB, an injected POJO or SesscionScoped Named class):

```
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

System.out.println("Number of services: " + services.length);
```

When this is run in a standalone Java Application it returns the 6 services as expected.
Furthermore I'm not running Jboss as a service but using standalone.bat (running this as administrator didn't help either), this was the most common problem in similar posts. I also tried `PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService()` and `PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices()` without luck.

I'm pretty much out of ideas, maybe that is a bug in JBoss 7? Or should the PrintServiceLookup be called in some special way?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Problem is jboss 7 specific and solution is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666786/printservicelookup-lookupprintservice-solution-in-jboss-as-7 .

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but it could be that a `SecurityManager` that is used by JBoss prevents this. The docs of class `PrintServiceLookup` say

> *A PrintServiceLookup implementor is recommended to check for the SecurityManager.checkPrintJobAccess() to deny access to untrusted code. Following this recommended policy means that untrusted code may not be able to locate any print services.*

[JBoss AS7: Security : Running under a Java Security Manager](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecurityRunningUnderAJavaSecurityManager)

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same problem. But adding an policy file didn't help. If you step through the code of lookup service it's not throwing an exception on the checkPrintJobAccess.

I think it's something with awt/windows class loading.