# PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintService solution in JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jsf-2, printing

I am trying to print a pdf document from my JSF web application.

When I call the method `findPrinter()` from main method, `PrintServices` are found, but when I call this method from web page `PrintService` are not found. Code mentioned below..

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    PrintTest printTest = new PrintTest();
    printTest.findPrinter();
 }

 public void findPrinter() {

    PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
    System.out.println("Print Services Length :: " + printServices.length);
    for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
        System.out.println("PrintService :: " + printService);
}

   <h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Print" action="#{printTest.findPrinter()}"/> 
   </h:form>
```

Any suggestions...

Comment: In case of the web application you will search for printer connected to the server, don't you?

Comment: yes, I will search for printer's configured to server..

Comment: how is it "not working" do you get any errors or just an empty list?

Comment: I am getting empty list...

Comment: when I run this application in Tomcat server, it is working fine.. but I am facing problem with Jboss AS..

Comment: 1.Add extra tag in modules/sun/jdk/main/module.xml of jbossAs as mentioned:  <path name="sun/print"/>                                           2.Open up resources.jar from your JRE, and extract                META-INF/services/javax.print.PrintServiceLookup and copy to location modules/sun/jdk/main/service-loader-resources/META-INF/services of JbossAS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add extra tag in modules/sun/jdk/main/module.xml of jbossAs as mentioned:
     **path name="sun/print"**
2. Open up resources.jar from your JRE, and extract
    META-INF/services/javax.print.PrintServiceLookup and copy to location 
    modules/sun/jdk/main/service-loader-resources/META-INF/services of JbossAS.
3. Restart JBoss and run the application.